# strstr through pointers in c language

Tags: c, pointers, strstr

is this the standard code for strstr i made????

```
char* fstrset(char *s,char *t)
{
    int b, i=0,j=0;

 while(*(s+i)!='\0')
 {
  if(*(t+j)=='\0')
   break;
  else if(*(s+i)==*(t+j))
   {
   i++;j++;b=1;
   }
  else
   { i++;b=0;j=0;
   }
 }

    if(b==0)
     return((char*)NULL);
    else if(b==1)
     return(s+i-j);
}
```

Comment: Your tag is wrong. This is not a C# question.

Comment: There's no standard code. Just standard behavior. Are you asking if you comply with the standard?

Comment: Why does this have a `C++` tag?

Comment: @sbi:  `strstr` is a valid standard C++ function.

Comment: @SHEHROZ: I see a conscious attempt to avoid any C library functions within your implementation. Is this a requirement?

Comment: @Thomas: By this logic, _every_ question that has a `C` tag should have a `C++` tag, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this right approach to write the code of strstr through pointers in c??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691043/is-this-right-approach-to-write-the-code-of-strstr-through-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

This is all the standard has to say about it:

> 7.21.5.7 The `strstr` function
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
>  #include <string.h> 
> char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> Description
>
> The strstr function locates the first
>   occurrence in the string pointed to by
>   s1 of the sequence of characters
>   (excluding the terminating null
>   character) in the string pointed to by
>   s2.
>
> Returns
>
> The strstr function
>   returns a pointer to the located
>   string, or a null pointer if the
>   string is not found. If s2 points to a
>   string with zero length, the function
>   returns s1.

So, it looks like you're missing `const` qualifiers on arguments.

As for style, note that `*(ptr+index)` can be replaced by `ptr[index]`, and `size_t` is the best type to use for indexing a pointer.

As for being a *common* way to implement it, compare with GCC's code:

```
char *
strstr (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  const char *p = s1;
  const size_t len = strlen (s2);

  for (; (p = strchr (p, *s2)) != 0; p++)
    {
      if (strncmp (p, s2, len) == 0)
    return (char *)p;
    }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: It's also worth looking at [glibc's implementation](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strstr.c;h=ef45f827584526e09c73426c5d63e3197f31a909;hb=HEAD), which uses a more complex algorithm to avoid the N^2 behaviour of the naive implementation.

Comment: @caf Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I wonder why glibc isn't in the GCC source tree, and why GCC isn't using the faster implementation.

Comment: It's because they're separate projects.  You can use GCC with other `libc` s - in fact it's quite common (eg on Mac OS X, Solaris, BSD, ...) (and you can use `glibc` with other compilers, although they do have to be quite gcc-like and it's not as common a case).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is buggy.  Given:

```
char *haystack = "fififi-trixabelle";
char *needle = "fifi-trixabelle";
```

`fstrset(haystack, needle)` returns incorrectly returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the bug mentioned by caf there are others:

1) Uninitialized b. If `s` points to `'\0'`, closing brace may be reached, omitting any return statements.

2) If characters match up to the end of string pointed to by `s` there is no check if the string pointed to by `t` ends too.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>What does this do? It looks like gibberish. Why adding pointers, and mixing them with ints? Sorry, but the whole thing doesn't make sense.</strike>

And to answer your question, i don't think so. But if you compile it and it runs, then yes.

Okay, your code does make sense when you look at it closer. Yes, it does look like it will compile, if thats what you mean by standard code.

Answer (score 0):

```
inline char* strstr(char* __s1, const char* __s2)
{
    return __builtin_strstr(const_cast<const char*>(__s1), __s2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick read through seems to show that the code works (there are probably edge cases that dont work). You tell us, does it work?

But why do it? just call strstr

Comment: There certainly are cases that don't work - see my answer for one.

Comment: ya it works i just want to implement the funtion. would call strstr next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'standard code', just the standard result.

It is unlikely that any implementation in a standard C library uses array indexing, so it is unlikely that your code matches any implementation in line-by-line detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* fstrstr(char *s1,char *s2)
{
 int i=0,flag=0;
 char *s4,*s3;
// s4 for retaining the value of s2
 s4 = s2;
 while(*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0')
 {
  if(*s1 == *s2)
  {
   *(s3+i) = *s1;
   s2++;
   s1++;
   i++;
   flag = 1;
  }
  else
  {
   i = 0;
   s1++;
//   Initialize s2 again from its address
   s2 = s4;
   flag = 0;
  }
 }
 if(flag == 1)
 {
  while(*s1 != '\0')
  {
   *(s3+i) = *s1;
   i++;
   s1++;
  }
  *(s3+i) = '\0';
 }
 if(flag == 1)
  return (s3);

 if(flag==0)
 {
  *s3 = NULL;
  return (s3);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standard code", only standard results.

It is unlikely that any implementation in the standard C library will use array indexes, so your code is unlikely to match any implementation in the line implementation.

Answer (score -1):

```
    char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
      char *a = s1, *b = s2;
      for (;;)
        if      (!*b)          return (char *)s1;
        else if (!*a)          return NULL;
        else if (*a++ != *b++) {a = ++s1; b = s2;}
    }
```